# Intelligent input into Java program using bash

Tags: java, bash, automated-tests

I am working on a bash script for automatically grading student assignments and am stumped on how to deal with random numbers.

A student program output looks like this, where it waits for an int input:

4 + 6 =

And my script needs to generate the correct input to make sure their program runs correctly and checks the response. The problem is that the numbers are not always 4 and 6, but rather any set of random numbers between 1 and 20.

So if the program prints "5 + 7 = ", my script needs to enter 12, but if it prints "20 + 12 = ", my script needs to enter 32. Is there a way to have a bash script do this? I don't know how to have it calculate the response on the fly. I've tried the coproc command but it hasn't worked the way I liked.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what "a student program looks like this" means. Do you have access to the source code? Does your test have to react based on a prompt?

Comment: The output looks like that. So yes, my script needs to react to their prompt and pass in a value

Comment: Bash would not be the way I'd go here.   This question suggests that you are not a developer yourself.  Is that true?

Comment: I really dont get what you are asking? When some program prints to the console, you can of course **read** that (using pipes, and stdin on the other program). You then parse the input, extract the numbers and add them.

Comment: But unrelated: are we really talking about programs that add up random numbers in the range of (1, 20)? What I mean is: are you sure you want to spend effort on something that is discussed in class for 5 minutes, and implemented in another 5 minutes?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is for grading student projects. Their program creates a quiz where it prompts with math questions and the user has to answer them. It then calculates their score, etc. I am trying to create a script that automatically "takes the quiz" so that I don't have to sit there and enter all of the responses manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should split the mathexpression into pieces and add them to a Stack. that it would look like this: |4|+|6|
Then you could try to convert the number into a real number. If it fail then you could ask if it is an operator like +,-,*,/. 
If you have done that, then just work down the Stack and calculate it. If you calculated it, then compare it to the input of the student.

Or the easy way:
You have to save the random numbers and calculate them after you generated them.

Sorry if I just completly misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the program output is in a single line, you can capture it using

```
read -r
```

then remove the "="

```
LINE = `echo $REPLY | sed 's#=.*##`
```

and have bash interpret it as a numeric variable

```
echo $((LINE))
```

Answer (score 0):

After further thought, it makes more sense to override the implementation of Math.Random() for the purpose of grading so that the student program always generates the same values.